# I want to remove 1st character from each line as its special and convert file to ; semicolon delimited file

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting, debugging

Source file is having a special character in starting of each row.
File is double space delimited.

Sample data file:

```
âNAME  ABC
âAGE  21
âADDRESS  XYZ street ABC city
âCONTACT  13244235
âDOJ  20181212
```

I want to remove `â` as its first and special character in each line and convert file to `;` (semicolon) delimited file.

Below code I have written which is working fine in UAT but its not working correctly in PROD:

`awk '{ print substr($0,1) }' FILE1.txt | sed 's/  /;/' > FILE2.txt`

UAT output (desirable output which is expected):

```
NAME;ABC
AGE;21
ADDRESS;XYZ street ABC city
CONTACT;13244235
DOJ;20181212
```

PROD output:

```
âNAME;ABC
âAGE;21
âADDRESS;XYZ street ABC city
âCONTACT;13244235
âDOJ;20181212
```

Same code is working fine in UAT i.e removing first character and converting file to `;` semicolon delimited, But in PROD its not removing 1st special character but converting file to semicolon delimited.

Output of `locale`:

```
locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Can anyone help me out on this ..?

Comment: @alecxs please don't put answers in comments. That circumvents the quality control tools of the site (voting) and can make others feel less inclined to answer if a solution has already been given.

Comment: @alecxs it was an imperfect solution (you had posted `sed 's/^â//' 's/ /;/' FILE1.txt > FILE2.txt` which _might_ fix the problem with the `â` (probably not though since I suspect that's an encoding issue and not an actual `â`), but would only change the first space on each line to a `;`. But that's _precisely_ why you shouldn't post things like that as comments. It was a "wrong" solution since it wouldn't actually work as intended, but nobody could downvote it.

Comment: @naresh, can you confirm that `sed -n '/^â/p' FILE1.txt` has output on your PROD machine? Also, what is "UAT" and "PROD"? What are the differences between them? What `locale` settings do the two machines have?

Comment: Hey  @terdon , UAT and PROD and nothing but different enviroment in IT industry where code is delivered to run on Real time data. in terms of settings .. they are always same with difference in memory thats' all

Comment: @Naresh. What locale is set?

Comment: locale is set to  en_US.UTF-8

Comment: @Naresh please [edit] your question and add i) the answer to my previous question about `sed -n '/^â/p' FILE1.txt`, ii) the output of `locale` on each machine, iii) the output of `file FILE1.txt` on each machine.

Comment: @teron, as i mentioned locale is set to en_US.UTF-8 for all variables.

Comment: ii.) sed -n '/^â/p' FILE1.txt command replaces â to another special symbol, i don't what that is.  iii). FILE1.txt is already mentioned above in question.

Comment: @naresh please ***edit*** your question to add the answers. And I asked for the output of `locale`. And don't tell me you don't know what it is, include the actual output. This, by the way, suggests that the file encoding is different.

Comment: guys guys please, i am looking for a solution here.... @terdon i know what locale is man.. i won't be able to give you actual output as its against organization policies.. and please use ANSWER button to post answer

Comment: @Naresh I am just trying to help you get an answer. All the details must be in the question because comments are easy to miss, hard to read and can be deleted without warning. The answer is almost certainly about the file's encoding, but you don't want to give us the information we would need to answer. If for some reason you can't post the output of standard commands you will at least have to describe it.

Comment: @terdon i am really glad man you are trying to help me and i respect it... but i have already given you all the information in above comments.

Comment: Note that `substr()` offsets are 1-based, so `substr($0,1)`  is the same as `$0` (except for the fact that it enforces a *string* type).

Comment: is that even a output or just a weird shell prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `â` you are seeing is almost certainly an encoding issue, and assuming all of your lines are supposed to start with a capital letter, you could try this:

```
LC_ALL=C sed 's/^[^A-Z]*//; s/   */;/g' FILE1.txt > FILE2
```

That will run the command using the `C` locale which should ensure that whatever character your `â` is isn't included in the A-Z range. Then, the sed command simply removes all characters not in the A-Z range from the beginning of each line, and then converts all occurrences of two or more spaces to `;`.

Comment: above suggestion seems to work in UAT but still have to test in PROD environment. Will confirm once done thanks

Comment: thanks a ton man above suggestions worked in PROD.

Comment: thanks a ton man @terdon, above suggestion worked perfectly in PROD.

Answer (score 4):

I think that you problem could be link to the character encoding, try to display the `FILE1.txt` in both env with

```
hexdump -C FILE1.txt
```

It can be coded as E-ascii or UTF-8 (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%82#Character_mappings)

To solve your problem, you can try to match both encoding:

```
        â in UTF-8                     â in other encoding
        |                              |
        v                              v
sed 's/\xc3\xa2//' FILE1.txt | sed 's/\xE2//' > FILE2.txt
```

Another solution could be to convert your file to a known encoding before processing it.

It might be dangerous not to test the PROD encoding.

Comment: hey @Mathieu,  I have tried hexdump command in both UAT and PROD with first 10 lines and it seems both matches.

Comment: I don't think so, its related to file encoding as i took the same file from prod and processed it in UAT and it works fine. I am not sure where to look at.

Comment: @Naresh, what is the encoding of "â"? in hexadecimal?

Comment: â  in hexadecimal is C3 A2

Comment: that should work i doubt you have tested well

Answer (score 2):

try

```
sed 's/^â//; s/   */;/g' FILE1.txt > FILE2.txt
```

And downvote if it doesn't work for you

Comment: @terdon thx, however i think the g is wrong

Comment: It won't hurt here. The OP stated it is a "double space delimited file", so although the example only has 2 fields, we may as well go for a more general solution that would also work for N fields.

Comment: was looking into cut command .. it seems i got the solution .. we can use cut command with -c 1- to cut 1st character and storing it to other file after replacing double space to ; semicolon through sed

Comment: @Naresh that won't work if the first "character" is a multi-byte UTF letter like `â`. Try `printf 'â' | wc -c`, it should print `2`, not `1`.

Comment: yeah its printing 2. i have tried above solution but seems to be not working..

Comment: @Naresh yep. Which is why I have asked you so many times to tell us if `sed -n '/^â/p' FILE1.txt` has output on your PROD machine. And show the output of the `file` command and the `locale` commands. If you do this, maybe someone will be able to find a solution.

Comment: @terdon, below is the output of locale:
locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

Answer (score 2):

To remove the first character of each line, it should be:

```
cut -c2- # not with the GNU implementation which is currently not multi-byte aware
sed 's/^.//'
awk '{print substr($0, 2)}' # note the 2 instead of 1 as offsets are 1-based
                            # not with mawk or other non-multi-byte aware awk
                            # implementations.
```

Beware however that for `.` to match that `â` character and `substr()` to work properly, that `â` has to be encoded as per the locale's encoding (see output of `locale charmap`).

To remove the first character and replace all sequences of whitespace with `;`, you can either do:

```
sed 's/^.//;s/[[:space:]]\{1,\}/;/g'
```

Or:

```
awk -v OFS=';' '{$0 = substr($0, 2); $1 = $1; print}'
```

(though beware the latter won't include a trailing `;` for lines that end in blank characters, and the list of blank characters that are considered as delimiters varies with the `awk` implementation and locale).

Now, also beware that `â` (U+00E2) is encoded as byte 0xe2 in the iso8859-1 charset (aka `latin1` and a few other single byte charsets). And that byte 0xe2 also happens to be the first byte of the encoding of a number of 3-byte  UTF-8 characters, among which are several Unicode whitespace character (like the U+2000 to U+200B spacing characters).

So, if you're seeing a `â` displayed in a latin1 terminal, it could be that the input actually contains U+2002 (EN SPACE) for instance encoded in UTF-8 (0xe2 0x80 0x82), and your terminal would display that `0xe2` as `â` and wouldn't show anything for 0x80 and 0x82 which are not in latin1.

To get rid of that EN SPACE, you'd need to either strip 1 character is a UTF-8 locale, or strip 3 characters in a single-byte locale (like one using latin1 or the C locale).

Comment: i have tried your suggestions 1st one is not changing anything .. 2nd suggestion is removing 1st letter of each attribute . For example name is ame

Comment: @Naresh, then your real input doesn't match what you've shown in your question. Post the output of `LC_ALL sed -n 'l;q' < your-file` or `<your-file head -n 1 | od -vtc -tx1` so we can see what the first line of that input actually contains at byte level.

Comment: LC_ALL  is blank in locale .. I have shared locale output above, hence its saying command not found.. For second command your-file head -n 1 | od -vtc its returning 0000000

Comment: @Naresh, sorry my bad, typo. I meant `LC_ALL=C sed -n 'l;q' < your-file`. That's `<your-file head -n 1 | od -vtc -tx1`, not `your-file head -n 1 | od -vtc -tx1`, as in you want to feed `your-file` into `head` so it can feed the first line of that to the octal dumper (here configured to display the hex and char value of each 1 byte of that line).

Comment: i have ran LC_ALL=C command its returning \n 342 before each attribute of file

Comment: @Naresh, octal 342 is hex 0xe2, so that's that's `â` in the iso8859-1 character set. That would mean that also your locale is using the UTF-8 charset, your terminal isn't and that data is not valid UTF-8 text, so you can't use text utilities in that locale to process it. Prepending `LC_ALL=C` to all the commands I gave could help.

Comment: thank you so much for your valuable time, Prepending LC_ALL=C worked in PROD as suggested by terdon above.